# Connect to MS Access MDB file from .netcore 3.1

Tags: ms-access, asp.net-core

i'm trying connection to MDB file using .netcore 3.1.
i tried using oledb but it's not working i guess because my pc is windows 10.
i tried using odbc and i'm getting the following error.`'ERROR [IM014] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] The specified DSN contains an architecture mismatch between the Driver and Application'` 
i have office 365 32 bit installed on my pc.

Comment: Edit question to show code.

Comment: maybe this can help; https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/702f0d9b-6cb9-49cf-9953-80d059711e60/the-specified-dsn-contains-an-architecture-mismatch-between-the-driver-and-application?forum=sqlgetstarted